# "Object required" error occurs when accessing series collection in excel chart using vba

Tags: excel, vba, charts, collections, series

I have this excel VBA Scripts that should returns the following information:

- Sheet Name
- Chart Name
- Chart Data Range
- Legend Entries (Series)
- Horizontal (Category) Axis Labels
- Top left Chart Co-ordinates on the sheet
- Chart Title

But I am getting The "Object required" error:
`.FullSeriesCollection(1).Values.Address`
because some of the charts do not have series, therefore property of the chart does not have any series in it. how can I tackle this problem?

```
Sub ChartInfo()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim ch As ChartObject
    Dim s As Series
    Dim i As Long
    
    For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        For Each ch In sh.ChartObjects
            With ch.Chart
                Debug.Print "Sheet Name: " & sh.Name
                Debug.Print "Chart Name: " & ch.Name
                Debug.Print "Chart Data Range: " & .FullSeriesCollection(1).Values.Address
                Debug.Print "Legend Entries (Series):"
                For Each s In .SeriesCollection
                    Debug.Print vbTab & s.Name
                Next s
                Debug.Print "Horizontal (Category) Axis Labels: " & .Axes(xlCategory).TickLabels.Address
                Debug.Print "Top left Chart Co-ordinates on the sheet: (" & ch.TopLeftCell.Row & ", " & ch.TopLeftCell.Column & ")"
                Debug.Print "Chart Title: " & .ChartTitle.Text
                Debug.Print "---------------------------------"
            End With
        Next ch
    Next sh
End Sub
```

Comment: Just check `Not <object> Is Nothing`.

Comment: The `Values` property of the `Series` does not return an object.

Comment: Yes, right, then as a quick and dirty way just check if it is possibe to do the assignment.

Comment: My point is that this approach will not work *at all*. You can't ever get an address from the `Values` property because it doesn't return an object, just an array of values.

Comment: @Rory so what is the alternative for  this? if I do not want to use `on error resume next`

Comment: Ah, okay, then the OP's code does not work at all even in case of a series.

Comment: If you need the address of the ranges involved, you have to parse the SERIES formula, which is not always straightforward.

Comment: what if I just get the formula instead of address. else I will manually check it

Comment: That will work - `.FullSeriesCollection(1).Formula`

Answer (score 0):

`FullSeriesCollection(1)` is a `Series` object. `Values` is an array of values of that series and has no `Address` property (it's an array of simple values).
The same is true for the x-Axis.

The only way I know to get the information (and change it using VBA) is by using the `Formula`-property of the series. This holds a formula as string that looks like this:

```
`=SERIES(Sheet1!$C$1:$C$7,Sheet1!$A$3:$A$7,Sheet1!$B$3:$B$7,1)`
```

- As you can see, there are 4 parameters, separated by a comma:
  The first (in the example `Sheet1!$C$1:$C$7`) is the legend for this series (may be empty).
- The second (`Sheet1!$A$3:$A$7`) are the x-axis values
- The third (`Sheet1!$B$3:$B$7`) is the data (y-axis value)
- The forth (`1`) is a simple number giving the printing order.

Now what you can do is simply split the formula:

```
Sub DumpSeriesInfo(ser As Series)
    Dim f As String, tokens() As String
    f = ser.Formula
    tokens = Split(f, ",")
    Dim p As Long
    p = InStr(tokens(0), "(")
    Debug.Print "Labels: " & Mid(tokens(0), p + 1)
    Debug.Print "X-Axis: " & tokens(1)
    Debug.Print "Data: " & tokens(2)
    p = InStr(tokens(3), ")")
    Debug.Print "Order: " & Left(tokens(3), p - 1)
End Sub
```

That would give you

```
Labels: Sheet1!$C$1:$C$7
X-Axis: Sheet1!$A$3:$A$7
Data: Sheet1!$B$3:$B$7
Order: 1
```

**Update**
as Rory pointed out, the formula can get more complicated when you select a list of single values. I made an example and got a formula that looked like this:

`=SERIES(Sheet1!$C$1:$C$7,Sheet1!$A$3:$A$7,(Sheet1!$D$2,Sheet1!$D$4,Sheet1!$D$6,Sheet1!$D$9,Sheet1!$D$11),1)`

So in this case the data values are a list of single values. Those values are enclosed in brackets and also separated by a comma. I changed the code to reflect this:

```
Sub GetSeriesData(ser As Series)
    Dim f As String, tokens() As String, formulas(1 To 3) As String
    f = ser.Formula
    Debug.Print f
    tokens = Split(f, ",")
    Dim p As Long
    p = InStr(tokens(0), "(")
    tokens(0) = Mid(tokens(0), p + 1)
    ' Cleanup first and last token.
    p = InStr(tokens(UBound(tokens)), ")")
    tokens(UBound(tokens)) = Left(tokens(UBound(tokens)), p - 1)
    
    ' Search for the three subformulas
    Dim tokenIndex As Long, formulaIndex As Long
    tokenIndex = 0
    For formulaIndex = 1 To 3
        formulas(formulaIndex) = tokens(tokenIndex)
        tokenIndex = tokenIndex + 1
        ' If part starts with "(", we have a group of single values and look for the matching closing ")"
        If Left(formulas(formulaIndex), 1) = "(" Then
            Do While Right(formulas(formulaIndex), 1) <> ")"
                formulas(formulaIndex) = formulas(formulaIndex) & "," & tokens(tokenIndex)
                tokenIndex = tokenIndex + 1
            Loop
        End If
    Next
    Debug.Print "Labels: " & formulas(1)
    Debug.Print "X-Axis: " & formulas(2)
    Debug.Print "Data: " & formulas(3)
    Debug.Print "Order: " & tokens(UBound(tokens))
End Sub
```

That gives:

```
Labels: Sheet1!$C$1:$C$7
X-Axis: Sheet1!$A$3:$A$7
Data: (Sheet1!$D$2,Sheet1!$D$4,Sheet1!$D$6,Sheet1!$D$9,Sheet1!$D$11)
Order: 1
```

Comment: nice! it looks appealing

Comment: That will work as long as you have simple charts. It is possible to have multiple discrete ranges included in the values and/or axis value ranges, which would cause this to produce incorrect results, just so you know.

Comment: Just for curiosity: Can you give an example how the formula looks in that case? --- Never mind, figured out by myself. You are right. Makes string handling a little bit more complicated...